# Proper use of HTML5 elements

Tags: css, html

I have my profile image and below it I want to place my name and a few things about me. I don't know what to use for the image div or if I even need a div for it. Are the h1 and p elements used properly?

**Snippet**

```
<div class="profile">

  <div><img src="profile_image.jpg"></div>
  <h1>first last</h1>

  <p>Coffee snob.</p>

</div>
```

**Full Body HTML**

```
<body>

  <div class="page">

    <div class="profile">

      <div><img src="profile_image.jpg"></div>
      <h1>first last</h1>

      <p>Coffee snob.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="sites">

      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><img src=""></a> <a href=""><img src=""></a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

The rest of the site are just app icons taking to my social media sites. There's no other content. My site also doesn't have a header or footer. Not sure if my profile class should be considered the header at this point for good SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to put the `div` around the image. Just style it to `display: block` (`img` defaults to `display: inline`)

```
<div class="profile">
  <img style="display: block" src="profile_image.jpg">
  <h1>first last</h1>
  <p>Coffee snob.</p>
</div>
```

Otherwise, the rest of the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend of what exactly you want to do with it but if I understand your question.
You don't need divs for your image just set up different image classes in your CSS.

```
.image1
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Then your HTML would look like

```
<img src="profile_image.jpg" class="image1">
```

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp for more information about how to actually set up alignments in your CSS

It might be worth using a div to style your text into a block or format it to look nice, etc. But you don't need to do it

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp  for div styling .

And finally abit of personal experience, spend an hour or 2 looking through W3Schools CSS section and learning the basics of styling it's a great way to learn the basic tools you need to work with CSS and make your pages look good !

**Edit** styling text

```
<h1>first last</h1>
<p>Coffee snob.</p>
```

so first you could style them in your css as the elements they are

```
h1 
{
text-align:left;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: underline;
}


p
{
text-align: right; 
}
```

Doing thing your HTML would look exactly as it is you wouldn't have to change anything. Obviously this is something you can only do once for all `<p>` and `<h1>` content and every time you use those tags without specifying a class for them it'll look exactly like whatever the above CSS is.

The other option is to do what I suggested with the image and give them a unique class.

```
p.body
{
text-align: right;
}
```

Here you'll need to add class to `<p>` jsut like you did for image which will look like

```
 <p class="body">Coffee snob.</p>
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Would you mind editing your answer to provide an example of formatting the text besides using a `h1` and `p`?

Comment: Ah, I knew that stuff. I thought you were thinking of something else I overlooked. haha  I do appreciate it though!